# nodejs Dialogflow v2 close a conversation from the fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How do I end my conversation from the webhook ?

Marking it within Dialogflow does nothing , basically does not stop it as I am using the webhook for fulfillment .

And if I add it to the code as below then it does not play the media.

```
// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
// https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs
const {dialogflow, Suggestions, MediaObject, Image} = require('actions-on-google');
// Import the firebase-functions package for Cloud Functions for Firebase fulfillment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Node util module used for creating dynamic strings
const util = require('util');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client with debug logging enabled.
const app = dialogflow({
  debug: true
});

// Do common tasks for each intent invocation
app.middleware((conv, framework) => {
  console.log(`Intent=${conv.intent}`);
  console.log(`Type=${conv.input.type}`);
  //kng
  console.log(`Arguments=${conv.arguments}`);
  console.log(`Arguments=${typeof(conv.arguments)}`);
  // Determine if the user input is by voice
  conv.voice = conv.input.type === 'VOICE';
  if (!(conv.intent === 'Default Fallback Intent' || conv.intent === 'No-input')) {
    // Reset the fallback counter for error handling
    conv.data.fallbackCount = 0;
  }
});

app.intent('Play Sound', (conv, {SoundType,duration}) => {

    const suggestions1 = new Suggestions('do this ', 'do that', 'do nothing');

    simple_response = 'this is a response from the webhook'

    conv.ask(simple_response)
    conv.ask(new MediaObject({
      name: SoundType,
      url: some_mp3file_url,
      icon: new Image({
        url: some_image_url,
        alt: 'Media icon'
      })
    }));


    conv.ask( suggestions1);

    //if I close from the code it doesnot play the sound
    conv.close();
    //if I comment out the close statement above then it does not close and toggling on the "set this intent as the end of  convesation does not seem to help."

  }
)
```

Update - This was intact a bug as pointed out by one of the comments . Reported to google and they fixed the same in April or May

Answer (score 0):

I can duplicate the issue, but it appears to be a bug - playing audio as part of the response and having it close after the audio finishes *used* to work. It is clearly supposed to be supported - the documentation and the simulator state that Suggestions aren't required if this is a final response.

The workaround is to create an additional Intent that handles the Action `actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS`. This Intent would then close the conversation.

Comment: I am assuming you are talking of this documentation https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits  And I have this feeling that it was working till a few days back. the problem with using Media status and waiting till the media is done playing is that the media could be hours long (aka 
 white noise). this makes it not suitable to wait to close till media is done playing.

Comment: No, that's not what I was talking about (although that is a known bug). I was specifically looking at your use of `conv.close()`. If you want to end it mid-playback, I'm not sure what you're asking in your question - please update your question to clarify.

Comment: Ok, then yes, this appears to be a bug.

Comment: thx and do you know why this does not work on google home ? this used to work till last week https://youtu.be/8cTaN4FXPxE maybe I need to create a seperate queston for this ?  basically the media work on google asssitnat on my phone but not on the google assistant device..

Comment: As I said, this appears to be a bug.